# Retrofit2 Singleton causes failed http requests after internet drops

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm trying to create a Retrofit Service using a super simple singleton. This seems to be working most of the time. Except, when I test the connection dropping by turning on airplane mode, the http request will fail as it should. But when I turn airplane mode off, the requests will continue to fail. I get this error: 
`HTTP FAILED: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout`

Here is the code I'm using:

```
class ServiceGenerator {
    private static ScanClient service = null;

    static ScanClient createService(Class<ScanClient> serviceClass, Context context) {
        if (service == null) {
            String apiBaseUrl = Constants.RETROFIT_BASE_URL;
            Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(apiBaseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

            OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

            if (Constants.PHP_DEBUG) {
                HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor()
                    .setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

                httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
            }

            httpClient.addInterceptor(new ReceivedCookiesInterceptor(context));
            httpClient.addInterceptor(new AddCookiesInterceptor(context));
            builder.client(httpClient.build());
            Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

            service = retrofit.create(serviceClass);
        }

        return service;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by handling timeouts.

```
        ...
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

        if (Constants.PHP_DEBUG) {
            HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor()
                .setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

            httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
        }

        httpClient.connectTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        httpClient.writeTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        httpClient.readTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        httpClient.addInterceptor(new ReceivedCookiesInterceptor(context));
        httpClient.addInterceptor(new AddCookiesInterceptor(context));
        builder.client(httpClient.build());
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This only kind of works. I tried this with 2, 5, and 10 minute timeouts. 2 and 5 minutes didn't work. When I used the 10 minute timeout, it finally worked, but at the 8 minute mark. That is too long to wait :(

Comment: Okay. I'm using this in a project I'm currently working on and 2 minutes worked effectively for me.
Should've mentioned you may need to test other options. Good to know it helped.